# How to get the bootstrap title values dynamically on clicking with the respective footers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

**Laravel View code:**

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
@foreach($deviceCategory as $deviceCategories)
<div class="col-sm-4">
<div class="panel panel-default">
 <div class="panel-heading">
 <div class="col-sm-1">
 <div id="deviceId" class="check">{{$deviceCategories-
 >deviceCategoryId}}</div>
 </div>
  <br/> 
 </div>
<div class="panel-body">
<div class="col-sm-2">
<h5><strong>{{$deviceCategories->deviceCategoryName}}</strong></h5>
<h6><button style="border:none; background-color: transparent;" 
disabled></button></h6>
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-1" align="center">
 <img src="{{asset(Storage::url('public/' . $deviceCategories-
 >image))}}" width="200" height="150">

 </div>
  </div>
 <div class="panel-footer" align="right"><a href="" data-
 toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" 
 class="getDeviceCategoryId">SELL THIS CATEGORY</a></div>
 </div>
 </div>
 @endforeach
 </div>
```

This is my view code. Here I am displaying the values dynamically that are fetched from db. Then When I click with the panel-footer (ie.,SELL THIS CATEGORY) , I need to alert the respective value in the panel-heading(ie.,{{$deviceCategories->deviceCategoryId}})

**SCRIPT CODE**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">


   $(document).ready(function() {
   $('.getDeviceCategoryId').click(function() {
    var value=$('#deviceId').text();
   alert(value);

  });
  });
```

This is my script code I have tried. But I get only the first id value for all panel footers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correct and you want to get particular `<div id="deviceId">` text while click on `SELL THIS CATEGORY`:

**Laravel View code:**

```
<div id="deviceId" class="check">{{$deviceCategories->deviceCategoryId}}</div>
```

*TO*

```
<div id="deviceId" class="check device-{{$deviceCategories->deviceCategoryId}}">{{$deviceCategories->deviceCategoryId}}</div>
```

*AND*

```
<div class="panel-footer" align="right"><a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" class="getDeviceCategoryId">SELL THIS CATEGORY</a></div>
```

*TO*

```
<div class="panel-footer" align="right">
    <a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" class="getDeviceCategoryId" data-id="{{$deviceCategories->deviceCategoryId}}">SELL THIS CATEGORY</a>
</div>
```

**SCRIPT CODE**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.getDeviceCategoryId').click(function() {
        var dataId = $(this).attr("data-id");

        //if you use newer jQuery >= 1.4.3
        //var dataId = $(this).data('id');

        var value = $('.device-' + dataId).text();
        alert(value);
    });
});
```

**UPDATE**
**SCRIPT CODE**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.getDeviceCategoryId').on('click', function() {
        var dataId = $(this).attr("data-id");

        //if you use newer jQuery >= 1.4.3
        //var dataId = $(this).data('id');

        var value = $('.device-' + dataId).text();
        alert(value);
    });
});
```

**UPDATE**

*Your route should be like:* `Route::get('products/{dataId}','Categories@products')->name('products');`

*Your Laravel View code should be like:*

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
    @foreach($deviceCategory as $deviceCategories)
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <div class="col-sm-1">
                        <div id="deviceId" class="check">{{$deviceCategories->deviceCategoryId}}</div>
                    </div>
                    <br/> 
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <h5><strong>{{$deviceCategories->deviceCategoryName}}</strong></h5>
                        <h6><button style="border:none; background-color: transparent;" disabled></button></h6>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-1" align="center">
                        <img src="{{asset(Storage::url('public/' . $deviceCategories->image))}}" width="200" height="150">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-footer" align="right"><a href="{{ url('products/'.$deviceCategories->deviceCategoryId)}}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" class="getDeviceCategoryId">SELL THIS CATEGORY</a></div>
             </div>
         </div>
     @endforeach
 </div>
```

Here no need JQ script...

Comment: I have made the changes.But it alerts nothing

Comment: Any error? you can check JS error into browser console

Comment: @nishanthi: Get ride for [How to diagnosis the JS error into browser](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/javascript/diagnose-javascript-errors)

Comment: No errors where displayed on the browser console sir

Comment: No error means code fine, now check my *UPDATE SCRIPT CODE*

Comment: Sorry.I have made the changes,but it displays nothing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151770/discussion-between-addweb-solution-pvt-ltd-and-nishanthi).

Answer (score 0):

Try this way -

```
    <div class="panel-footer" align="right">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-deviceid="{{$deviceCategories-
 >deviceCategoryId}}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"   class="getDeviceCategoryId">SELL THIS CATEGORY
        </a>
    </div>
```

and change your jQuery code to -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.getDeviceCategoryId').click(function() {
        var value=$(this).attr('data-deviceid');
        alert(value);
    });
});
```